# Changes not reflect on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal

I'm new to the docker, I'm using windows 11, while trying to do the changes to the code, I found that the code changes did not reflect on docker, unless I remove every container and image and rebuild then only reflect. This is too troublesome and time consuming, is there any other way to make it auto watch the changes and reflect automatically?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "9002:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpassword
    networks:
      - internal
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: web:1.0.1
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9001:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 9004:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: user
      PMA_PASSWORD: pw
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 4000M
    networks:
      - internal
volumes:
  db_volume:
  drupal-data:
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM drupal:9.2.5-php7.4-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

COPY ./k8s/php.ini "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY ./k8s/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer install

# Install php-redis - this is for drupal redis module
# RUN pecl install -o redis && \
#   echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini
  
# # Installing modules
# RUN composer require 'acquia/lightning:~5.2.0'
# RUN composer require 'cweagans/composer-patches:^1.6.0'
# RUN composer require 'oomphinc/composer-installers-extender:^1.1 || ^2'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/advagg:^4.1'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/autosave_form:^1.2'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/backup_migrate:^5.0'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/conditional_fields:^4.0@alpha'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/entity_reference_revisions:^1.9'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/field_group:^3.1'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/http_client_manager:^2.5'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/moderated_content_bulk_publish:^2.0'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/pathauto:^1.8'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/quick_node_clone:^1.14'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/svg_image:^1.14'
# RUN composer require 'drupal/svg_image_field:^2.0'

# # Installing other dependencies
# RUN composer require 'phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.18'
# RUN composer require 'lodash-php/lodash-php:^0.0.7'

# RUN composer require drush/drush 10.6 && ln -s $(pwd)/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

RUN ln -s /var/www/html/docroot /var/www/html/docroot/tv

COPY ./k8s/php.min.ini "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/php.ini"

# RUN rm "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/docroot/sites/default/files

RUN apache2ctl restart

EXPOSE 80
```

I'm using `docker compose up -d` to start the website

What am I doing wrong for this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to `map local code directory to the container directory`.

For that you need to add this line inside your `volumes in web`:

```
 volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html  # This maps the local code directory to the container directory
    - drupal-data:/var/www/html
```

> With help of this chnages will be reflected inside the container
> without having to rebuild the image

Comment: adding 2 line to the volumes of web? tried, not working